Magic fails to install Mojo dependencies
I cannot use the Mojo dependency called lightbug_http in a fresh Mojo project.
magic init hello_web --format mojoproject
cd hello_web
magic shell

Printing «Hello world» works fine.
Then I add https://repo.prefix.dev/mojo-community to the list of channels in mojoproject.toml.
magic add lightbug_http
magic install

Then I modify my src/main.mojo:
from lightbug_http import Welcome, Server

fn main() raises:
    print ("Hello world")
    var server = Server()
    var handler = Welcome()
    server.listen_and_serve("0.0.0.0:8080", handler)

Then I launch the program:
mojo run src/main.mojo 
hello_web/.magic/envs/default/lib/mojo/small_time.mojopkg:0:0: error: expected mlir::TypedAttr, but got: @stdlib
hello_web/.magic/envs/default/lib/mojo/small_time.mojopkg:0:0: note: in bytecode version 6 produced by: MLIR20.0.0git
hello_web/src/main.mojo:1:1: error: unable to load package 'hello_web/.magic/envs/default/lib/mojo/small_time.mojopkg'
from lightbug_http import Welcome, Server
^
mojo: error: failed to parse the provided Mojo source module

I also noticed different rights on the packages installed from init and the new ones:
(hello_web) ➜  hello_web ls -l .magic/envs/default/lib/mojo
total 45268
-rwxr-xr-x 1 thomas thomas 1971956 31 déc.  12:01 algorithm.mojopkg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 thomas thomas  715410 31 déc.  12:01 autotune.mojopkg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 thomas thomas 1433315 31 déc.  12:01 benchmark.mojopkg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 thomas thomas 1094280 31 déc.  12:01 buffer.mojopkg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 thomas thomas  788720 31 déc.  12:01 compile.mojopkg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 thomas thomas  707945 31 déc.  12:01 compiler_internal.mojopkg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 thomas thomas    1705 31 déc.  12:01 compiler.mojopkg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 thomas thomas  714424 31 déc.  12:01 complex.mojopkg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 thomas thomas 9930965 31 déc.  12:01 gpu.mojopkg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 thomas thomas  974993 31 déc.  12:01 kv_cache.mojopkg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 thomas thomas 3348271 31 déc.  12:01 layout.mojopkg
-rw-r--r-- 1 thomas thomas 2109465 31 déc.  12:04 lightbug_http.mojopkg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 thomas thomas 7079591 31 déc.  12:01 max.mojopkg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 thomas thomas 2515744 31 déc.  12:01 _mlir.mojopkg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 thomas thomas 1036088 31 déc.  12:01 runtime.mojopkg
-rw-r--r-- 1 thomas thomas  823950 31 déc.  12:04 small_time.mojopkg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 thomas thomas 7338653 31 déc.  12:01 stdlib.mojopkg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 thomas thomas  757942 31 déc.  12:01 subprocess.mojopkg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 thomas thomas 1487368 31 déc.  12:01 tensor_internal.mojopkg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 thomas thomas    1748 31 déc.  12:01 tensor.mojopkg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 thomas thomas 1468408 31 déc.  12:01 tensor_utils_internal.mojopkg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 thomas thomas    1467 31 déc.  12:01 tensor_utils.mojopkg

Here is my environment:

magic 0.5.1 - (based on pixi 0.37.0)
mojo 24.6.0 (4487cd6e)

Thanks for your help.
